# Drupal 7 and Page Manager: add Selection rules based on dates

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-panels

I have a content type **article** with a **field date**.

I am trying to fire a variant from Page Manager by defining a **selection rule based on a date field**.

What I am trying to do is applying this variant when

- the node type is article
- **field date, start date < now < field date, end date**

I can define the first condition but I can't figure out how to make a condition based on a date. Is it possible or not? I couldn't find more information about this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us how you would define the first condition? Questions about code should contain code if possible - that will make it easier to understand and solve the problem.

Comment: The first condition is simply defined by adding a selection rule on Node: type. 
The problem is with the second condition: field date, start date < now < field date, end date. If I try to add a new Selection rule on Node article: Date field I can specify what should be the precise value of the date, but can't make a condition with "in between".

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make this work, so in the end I wrote a custom module without using Page Manager. If somebody has a solution though please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this finally by writing a PHP Code Selection Rule.

I got from the exposed $contexts variable the start and end values for date field and I wrote a simple condition to check if "now" is in between the two dates.

Beware that the dates are stored in UTC format in the field and your site/users might be in a different timezone.

Comment: 6 years after : and would you share your PHP code please , because I have the same need :)